# Unable to make connections from a deployed App Maker app to Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

I had a working App Maker application which uses the Directory API and the default Cloud SQL instance that gets created for the App Maker.

Before it was working fine and I was able to retrieve data from the Admin Console and insert them into the Cloud SQL database. Now it stopped working and when I check logs, I see the following:

> Exception: Authorization Failed. More information: Unable to fetch
>   tokens for CloudSql connection:

[image]

I have not got any changes to the code and I did not modify anything. I only created a new deployment and I did change the product name in the OAuth Consent screen in the app's project properties to make it more use friendly...

I don't know what parts of the code to share since I did not change/type any new code and nothing in the error above points to anything specific about any part in the code...

Thanks a lot for any feedback and help on this!

Comment: This is totally weird. Make sure your SQL connection is right though.

Comment: In addition to @Morfinismo , it may be helpful to read [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/how-tos/authorizing) just to check if there is something you are missing. Also, reading other issues related to fetch tokens, talks about cloudsqlproxy. Are you using it?